# React Native Emulator in Atom

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-emulator, atom-editor

I have just started working on "react Native" using Atom IDE. I'm able to run react native codes in iOS using atom-Xcode (Simulator) but not on android. Does "Atom" support any emulator so that i can test my codes in Android too?